# how to remove first line from a huge text file - windows cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

how to remove first line in a super huge text file (min lines: 65536), using CMD (without any installing)?

example input file:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

output file after I run the CMD:

```
line2
line3
line4
```

I have tried

```
more +1 "input.txt" > "output.txt"
```

but the max limit line in text file is 65535.

thank you all in advanced.

ps: super newbie in coding scripting.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71841990), to get a better idea of how you may be able to do it using the built-in PowerShell, and any potential issues with those methodologies.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most efficient way in `CMD`, but this should work in `Powershell`:

```
get-content input.txt | select -Skip 1 | set-content "output.txt"
```

Comment: I woud advise not to use this answer. JhonnyG, please take a look at the question and answers I linked in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74151805/how-to-remove-first-line-from-a-huge-text-file-windows-cmd#comment130920894_74151805), to see why.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\hugefile.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR /f "skip=1usebackqeol=|delims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO ECHO %%b
)>"%outfile%"

FC "%filename1%" "%outfile%"
```

Some cautions:

empty lines will be ignored

I've used `eol=|` to set the end-of-line character to `|`. Any line containing `|` is deemed to terminate at `|`. The default end-of-line character is `;`.

Worked for me with 150,000 lines of "normalish" text - not containing the more rarely-used symbols.